VLC call via SUDO on Raspberry PI 4 (Linux) gives error [010209e8] . Is it a rights issue to sound files?
Can't seem get vlc module to run in python as sudo - raspberry pi 4 env
Trying to set up a self run app on my raspberry pi that runs a Gonk droid.
I've installed vlc to be able to play the sounds.
When I try to run the app with sudo (I've been told I need this ability to get the python app to run as an autostart script at boot) I get this error message
$ sudo python GonkRunVLC.py [010209e8] vlcpulse audio output error: PulseAudio server connection failure: Connection refused [01051b50] vlcpulse audio output error: PulseAudio server connection failure: Connection refused
Making the assumption it is a rights issue, can someone clue me in? Thanks.
when I run it without sudo it runs just fine!
The audio files are one sub directory below the app.... Ex: /home/me/programs/sounds/sound.mp3 Ex: python script is in on /home/me/programs/
~/my_programs $ python GonkRunVLC.py (Runs)

~/my_programs $ sudo python GonkRunVLC.py

 [010209e8] vlcpulse audio output error: PulseAudio server connection failure: Connection refused [01051b50] vlcpulse audio output error: PulseAudio server connection failure: Connection refused

